# How to reduce second by second from total amount of time in c# asp.net?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, timer

I have a variable called "Totaltime" in my program. I assign the variable (in seconds) as Totaltime = 3600. Now i want to reduce the time by 1 sec for each Tick event and show the reducing time in label or litera control.Can anyone please tell the C# ASP.NET coding to implement this?

Comment: You need javascript, not a server-side technology.

Comment: `Totaltime--;` or what is your question?

Comment: http://refactormycode.com/codes/302-countdown-timer-minutes-seconds-javascript#refactor_74241

Answer (score 1):

Even despite the fact, that this task cannot be done purely with server-side code, you can do it be using the following client and server code:


In your .aspx file, put the following javascript into the <head> part of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var timer = 3600, timeCont, t, timerOn = 0, timePanel
function countTimer() {
    timeCont.value = timer;
    timePanel.innerHTML = hms(timer);
    timer--;
    t = setTimeout("countTimer()", 1000);
}
function playTimer(obj) {
    if (timeCont == null || timeCont == "undefined") timeCont = document.getElementById("timerval");
    if (timePanel == null || timePanel == "undefined") timePanel = document.getElementById("timepanel");
    if (!timerOn) {
        timerOn = 1;
        countTimer();
        obj.value = timerLabel[1];
    } else {
        timerOn = 0;
        clearTimeout(t);
        obj.value = timerLabel[0];
    }
}
function hms(secs) {
    time = [0, 0, secs];
    for (var i = 2; i > 0; i--) {
        time[i - 1] = Math.floor(time[i] / 60);
        time[i] = time[i] % 60;
        if (time[i] < 10) time[i] = '0' + time[i];
    };
    return time.join(':');
}
function autoStartTimer() {
    playTimer(this);
}
window.onload = autoStartTimer;
</script>
```

Then put the following HTML controls into the <body> of your page:

```
<asp:Literal ID="litTimerLabels" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
<input type="hidden" name="timerval" id="timerval" value=""/>
<div id="timepanel" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;float:left;padding:2px 20px 0 0;"></div>
<asp:Button ID="btnDoStuff" runat="server" Text="Get number of remaining seconds on server side" OnClick="btnDoStuff_Click" />
```

Last step would be to add some functions into the .aspx.cs of your page to handle the time left on backend:

```
// Get elapsed time in seconds after postback has occured
protected void btnDoStuff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int secondsLeft = GetSecondsLeft();
}    

private int GetSecondsLeft()
{
    int formSecondsLeft = 0;
    if (Request.Form["timerval"] != null &&
        int.TryParse(Request.Form["timerval"], out formSecondsLeft))
    {
        // Keep in mind, that this can be a negative number if more than 3600 seconds elapsed!
        return formSecondsLeft;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This should be all you need. Have fun coding!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Server side Code (ASP.Net/C#). You need client side code (javascript) to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can add a updatepanel like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Timer runat="server" id="UpdateTimer" interval="5000" ontick="UpdateTimer_Tick" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="TimedPanel" updatemode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="UpdateTimer" eventname="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" id="DateStampLabel" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and the codebehind

```
protected void UpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateStampLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Good point Kim, but this will make one partial roundtrip for every interval so in this case every second which may be or may not be a problem. My solution may not be as nice as yours, but it gets the job done and it decreases the counter on client side without making any unnecessary roundtrips.